# Blazor: How to invoke JavaScript after HTML is rendered

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a custom component and when it's rendered in the browser, I need to measure its size (in JavaScript) and call back to Blazor.

How do I register JavaScript to invoke after rendering of particular component is done?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Include a script in your wwwroot.
2. Reference it in index.html or _Host.cshtml file
3. In your component add `@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime`
4. Add a `@ref` to the element you wish to measure `<div @ref=MeasureMe>`
5. In your `@code` declare a field `ElementReference MeasureMe`
6. Override OnAfterRenderAsync and do `var whatever = JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<YourResultType>("yourJSFunctionName", MeasureMe)`

Note: If you have server side prerendering enabled, do not use JSRuntime for the first time until after `OnAfterRenderAsync` has been executed with `firstRender == true`.

Also note: Components do not re-render when the browser is resized.

I have a section on JSInterop on [Blazor University](https://blazor-university.com/javascript-interop/).